# Select command help

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

i have two tables

t1

```
movieid  showdate
1001    2011-05-23
1002    2011-05-23
1001    2011-05-23
1003    2011-05-23
1001    2011-05-22
1003    2011-05-22
1001    2011-05-22
```

t2

```
movieid  moviename
1001    saanu                                             
1002    ambika
1003    sarah
1004    hello
```

I want result as

```
moviename

saanu
```

when date is 2011-05-22

```
moviename

saanu
ambika
sarah
```

when showdate is between 2011-05-22 and 2011-05-23

Comment: And what's your problem, exactly? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Your datatype is Datetime or Date or Varchar ? Sql Version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`JOIN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517.aspx) the two tables

> By using joins, you can retrieve data
>   from two or more tables based on
>   logical relationships between the
>   tables. Joins indicate how Microsoft
>   SQL Server should use data from one
>   table to select the rows in another
>   table.
>
> A join condition defines the way two
>   tables are related in a query by:
>
> - Specifying the column from each table to be used for the join. A
>      typical join condition specifies a
>      foreign key from one table and its
>      associated key in the other table.
> - Specifying a logical operator (for example, = or <>,) to be used in
>      comparing values from the columns.

Statement

```
SELECT  DISTINCT moviename
FROM    t2
        INNER JOIN t1 ON t1.movieid = t2.movieid
WHERE   t1.showdate = '2011-05-22'
```

and

```
SELECT  DISTINCT moviename
FROM    t2
        INNER JOIN t1 ON t1.movieid = t2.movieid
WHERE   t1.showdate BETWEEN '2011-05-22' AND '2011-05-23'
```

would suffice

Comment: Is it worth mentioning the UNION statement? I couldn't decide if he wanted a single result set.

Comment: @MrEdmundo - I doubt that is OP's intention here but he should definitely look it up to add to his bag of tricks.

Answer (score 0):

OK so you might want to look in to [JOINS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517.aspx) and  the WHERE statement using AND/OR.

For example

```
SELECT * FROM t2
INNER JOIN t1 ON t2.movieid = t1.moveid
WHERE (showdate = '2011-May-22 and moviename = 'saanu') OR (showdate between '2011-May-22' AND '2011-May-23')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.movie_name
FROM t1, t2
WHERE t1.movieid = t2.movieid
AND t1.showdate = to_date('2011-05-22','YYYY-MM-DD')
OR t1.showdate BETWEEN to_date('2011-05-22','YYYY-MM-DD') AND to_date('2011-05-23','YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
select moviename from t2 join t1 on t1.movieid=t2.movieid and showdate='2011-05-22'
```

where moviename='saanu'

2.

```
select moviename from t2 join t1 on t1.movieid=t2.movieid and showdate between '2011-05-22' and '2011-05-23'
```